# Notepad++ Edit syntax highlighting for PHP?

Tags: php, notepad++

I'd like to edit the syntax highlighting for PHP in Notepad++:

1. To have variables starting with `$_` in a different color than variables starting with only `$`
2. To have operators like `{} () []` in different colors than operators like `& =`

Is it possible to change the highlighting to be this in-depth? How?

Answer (score 14):

### This is Possible

In Notepad++, define a new language by clicking *View* **>** *User-Defined Dialogue...*

Give the language a name (e.g. myPHP). Set the ext (file extension abbreviation) to **php**. Define the color coding for the global variables and for the brackets, braces and parentheses, etc. Close the Dialoague.

That is all. The formatting for myPHP which conflicts with the formatting for PHP will override the formatting for PHP, i.e. if the file has a .php extension.

More information: [Notepad++ Wiki](http://docs.notepad-plus-plus.org/index.php?title=User_Defined_Languages#Built-in_versus_User_Defined_Languages)

Comment: The last step kind of makes this less useful than it potentially could be. But wow, I didn't know this feature existed.

Comment: @BoltClock, I also just learned about this now. I have edited my answer. It seems one can give the userdefined language the same file extension. Then it will also work.

Comment: I disagree.  Creating a custom language takes much longer than editing an existing language; therefore, this isn't the answer users coming to this page are seeking out.  It's a waste of time for users seeking this question.  This answer should not have been posted and is flagged for removal.  Either the question title should be changed such that people not seeking this issue aren't drawn here, or we should try to find a real answer.

Answer (score 6):

To edit the syntax highlighting in `Notepad++`, follow these steps:

- Go to `Settings`, then `Style`. The configurator dialog opens.
- Select language `php`
- Select the style based on your criteria
- Save

Comment: Any ideas how to define a new group in order to separate constants from functions? It's annoying to use the same color for them when they are totally different things...

Answer (score 0):

For me it was something different... I tried everything mentioned above but it did not work (Style configurator - global overwrites were off). When I manually changed the language to (almost) any other, it was colored, when I changed back to PHP it was not - it was shown as a pure text file, even though the file extension was .php.
So, the solution is to add the opening tag in front of the file:
`<?`
Actally my code is part of a complex framework which processes the PHP snippets in a different way, so I do not need to enter this tag. As it is required for Notepad++ to work, I commented it out and it still works nice:
`//<?`
There is no need for a closing tag.
[image: without <? tag]
[image: with <? tag commented]