# How to coloring TRUE and FALSE in xml Language in Notepad++

Tags: xml, notepad++

I'm looking for a way to color "TRUE" and "FALSE" in XML documents opened in Notepad++. I tried use Style token and marker but when you close Notepad++ they disappear. I tried to define my language but I do not know how use XML coloring as a base and then add TRUE and FALSE.

I tried editing `stylers.xml` and `langs.xml`, but after doing so nothing changed.

Comment: see this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4474041/notepad-edit-syntax-highlighting-for-php?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: I try that and it do not work. Maybe i do something wrong but there are 3 steps to make. 
Create new->myXML. 
Set Ext.:xml (i try php to) 
Close -> reset program -> set new language